# How can I change the coordinates for the iframe google map to print different results depending on the coordinates passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, iframe

I have managed to create a page where a user can click and change access the google maps using the following code.

```
<tr>
    <td>Coordinates:</td>
    <td>
        <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=MY%20LOCATION@{{place.place.lat}},{{place.place.lng}}">{{place.place.lat}},{{place.place.lng}}</a>
    </td>
    <br />
</tr>
```

Also, this is an angularjs app.
Now I want to embed this map on my application with the same concept of changing the latitude and longitude when the user clicks on different places to show where that particular place.
How can I do this?
I have looked into iframe, but I can only use the fixed coordinates.

Comment: Can you not just update the latitude and longitude coordinates in the iframe when you click on something?

Comment: That is what I want to know, but I cannot find anything.

Comment: I mean, litterly change the `src` of the `iframe`.

Comment: what would I changed it to? I have tried src="http://maps.google.com/?q=MY%20LOCATION@{{place.place.lat}},{{place.place.lng}}", it fails to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind an object with coordinates property on your controller to the google-map center directive property and update the property if somebody commits a search.

Comment: This is very useful thanks as I was looking to see how i link angualr and google maps